# Marshal managed string[] to unmanaged char**

Tags: c#, c++, string, marshalling

This is my c++ struct (Use Multi-Byte Character Set)

```
typedef struct hookCONFIG {
    int threadId;
    HWND destination;

    const char** gameApps;
    const char** profilePaths;
} HOOKCONFIG;
```

And .Net struct

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct HOOKCONFIG {
    public int threadId;
    public IntPtr destination;

    // MarshalAs?
    public string[] gameApps;

    // MarshalAs?
    public string[] profilePaths;
}
```

I got some problem that how do I marshal the string array?
When I access the struct variable "profilePaths" in C++ I got an error like this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in App.exe
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an 
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

```
MessageBox(0, cfg.profilePaths[0], "Title", MB_OK); // error ... Orz
```

Comment: Can you try it commenting out the HWND/IntPtr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way: Change prototype to IntPtr[]:

```
public IntPtr[] gameApps;
public IntPtr[] profilePaths;
```

Now when you call you need to roughly the following psudo-code:

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(string);
gameApps = new IntPtr[] { GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle) };

// Unmanaged call

handle.Free();
```